# How to get multiple div elements text inside a list tag while scrolling page with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I have the following webpage https://www.skroutz.gr/s/15013958/Hasbro-Monopoly-Classic-Game.html from which I want to get per seller the price,availability,seller name.

They are inside a list element as divs so I did the following

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\chromedriver.exe')

browser.get("https://www.skroutz.gr/s/15013958/Hasbro-Monopoly-Classic-Game.html")
time.sleep(1)

elem = browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

no_of_pagedowns = 20

while no_of_pagedowns:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.2)
    no_of_pagedowns-=1

post_elems = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".card.js-product-card")

for post in post_elems:
    print(post.text)
```

So far I get the data as a whole text and not by div. How to get price,availability and seller per post

Shall I do the following? or is there any more correct way?

```
for post in post_elems:
    prices = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".price")
    sellers = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector(".shop-name")
    availability = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("p.availability")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `post` element to locate the data, it will find only the data belongs to the specific post

```
data = []
for post in post_elems:
    price = post.find_element_by_css_selector(".price").text
    seller = post.find_element_by_css_selector(".shop-name").text
    availability = post.find_element_by_css_selector("p.availability").text

    # add to list of lists
    data.append([price, seller, availability])

    # print
    print(f'price: {price} seller: {seller} availability: {availability}')
```

Comment: But how I will put them each of them in a list like [price1,avail1,seller1],[price2,avail2,seller2].. ?

Comment: Define an empty list first before the `for` loop. Then append all elements into that list.

Comment: @Nikos Updated my answer, you can create a list and append new list each time.

Comment: @Guy Do you think I should place my for loop inside while loop for scrolling or is no need? Thank you very much

Comment: @Nikos There is no lazy loading, so it might not be necessary to scroll at all. But the best way to find out is to try :)

Comment: @Guy Its working fine but how to fix getting some prices like ['20,00 €'] instead of 20,00 € when using price = post.find_element_by_css_selector(".price").text.strip().split('\n')[5] I use this because for some prices I get ['21,99 €', '+ 0,00 €', 'Shipping', '+ 2,00 €', 'COD', '23,99 €']

Comment: @Nikos It's hard to answer questions in the comments, if you have a new question you should post a new question with the current code.